# "Working as a teacher is my dream." or "To work as a teacher is my dream."

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> 1. Working as a teacher is my dream.
> 2. To work as a teacher is my dream.

What's the difference between these sentences?
I've heard that infinitives is more appropriate than gerunds for expressing the future situation.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: If you are currently working as a teacher and it is your dream job, use the first sentence.  Sometimes people visualize themselves working as a teacher in the future and phrase it as if they are experiencing it happening.  They might say "To be working as a teacher is my dream", or leave off the "to be", as in your first sentence.  The second sentence is wishful thinking, referring to a hypothetical future event.

Comment: @fixer1234 This is not always the case. The meaning changes based on context.  In this case these are non-finite verb and hence they are un-tensed.

Comment: Oh I wanted to say "non finite clause".

Answer (score 1):

> working as a teacher

has more the meaning of *teaching*

> to work *as* a teacher

has more the meaning

> to work *like* a teacher *(works)*

in terms of hours and pay and workload

Comment: "working like a teacher" means "working in the way a teacher does", while "working as a teacher" means you are a teacher.